# C# unit test assert datetime

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert

I have a unit test on `TimeSpan`, and I don't know if I'm doing it right.

TEST CASE:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper around TimeSpan.TryParse that avoids out parameters. 
    /// Tries to parse a string as a TimeSpan and returns the parsed value as a TimeSpan or null if parsing failed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toParse">A string containing a value to convert</param>
    /// <param name="formatProvider">An object that provides culture-specific formatting information</param>
    /// <returns>The value parsed as a TimeSpan or null if parsing failed</returns>
        public static TimeSpan? ParseTimeSpan(this string toParse, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        TimeSpan value;
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(toParse, formatProvider, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

UNIT TEST:

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void ParseTimeSpanTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("5:33 pm"), "5:33".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("9:22 AM"), "9:22 AM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("8:22 pm"), "8:22 pm".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("7:22:44 AM"), "7:22:44 AM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("9:22:44 pm"), "9:22:44 pm".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("13:22:14"), "13:22:14".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("23:59:00"), "23:59:00".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        Assert.AreEqual(null, "25:59:00".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(null, "23:70:00 ".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(null, "23:59:75".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Assert.AreEqual(null, "five thirty".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


    }




    private static DateTime ParseTime(string time)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(time, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: Does it do what you think it should be doing?  It's not really possible for us to know what you expect, and therefore whether it's giving you your expected result.

Comment: I don't get the reason why you need a UnitTest there. Your method basically does the same as TryParse.

Comment: My first time writing unit test, so im expexting it should do what explain above "tries to parse a string as a timespan and returns the parsed value as a timespan or a null if fail"

Comment: And i dont think what im doing is right for Timespan test

Comment: You appear to be asserting that a nullable timespan is equal to a datetime. This will never be true.

Comment: The TryParse function you are wrapping was designed to avoid the implementation you are building here.  You are essentially forcing null propagation rather than using the very correct and convenient TryParse method.  Re-evaluate your design because I think you may have made a wrong turn somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a misconception between the types DateTime and TimeSpan.  DateTime is a datatype meant to represent a point in time, e.g. July 4, 1776 at 12 pm.  TimeSpan is meant to represent elapsed time/duration, i.e. the race lasted 12 hours and 36 minutes.

You can take the difference of two DateTimes to produce a TimeSpan.  Trying to parse a time into a timespan is difficult to do.  For instance, how does one convert 9:30 AM into a TimeSpan?

If you are looking for how to test TimeSpan, perhaps the below will help.

```
 public static TimeSpan? ParseTimeSpan(this string toParse, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        TimeSpan value;
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(toParse, formatProvider, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }

[TestMethod()]
public void ParseTimeSpanTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("5:33"), "5:33".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("9:22"), "9:22".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("8:22"), "8:22".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("7:22:44"), "7:22:44".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("9:22:44"), "9:22:44".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("13:22:14"), "13:22:14".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(ParseTime("23:59:00"), "23:59:00".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    Assert.AreEqual(null, "22:59:00 AM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(null, "23:70:00 PM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(null, "23:59:75 AM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Assert.AreEqual(null, "five thirty PM".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    var dt = DateTime.Now;
    Assert.AreEqual(dt.AddHours(1) - dt, "1:00".ParseTimeSpan(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

private static TimeSpan ParseTime(string time)
{
    return TimeSpan.Parse(time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i niw understand what timespan is. And I already did a test for datetime so I won't be doing another one. What i wanted to know is how i could test timespan. Thanks again

Comment: I've updated the answer above with examples of how to test timespan. Note the last test where I'm taking the difference of two DateTime's and comparing it to the result of the ParseTimeSpan Method.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks